# Are the medicinal plants in Sri Lanka proofs of Hanuman?

Tags: rama, hanuman

I am wondering whether the medicinal plants in Sri Lanka are really proof of Hanuman's feat of bringing the mountain of medicinal plants for Lord Ram's aid.

Or is their existence just a co-incidence, and does not have to do anything with Lord Hanuman's story?

Comment: Hanuman brought the mountain back when they were done using it, so no it's unlikely that any plants in Sri Lanka are from that mountain.

Comment: What are those medicinal plants, are they unique to Sri Lanka?

Comment: Here is what is considered as Sanjeevani: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selaginella_bryopteris